# linq lambda multiple group joins

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql, entity

I am trying to get a list of product along with its rating, comments and views. PID is product ID column without foreign key relationship.

Product -

```
Id  Name
1   P1
2   P2
```

Rating -

```
Id  PID Rating
1   1   5
2   1   4
3   2   3
```

Comments -

```
Id  PID Comment
1   1   Good
2   1   Average
3   2   Bad
```

Views -

```
Id  PID View
1   1   500
2   1   200
3   2   10
```

My class would look like this –

```
Public Class Product{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Rating> Ratings{ get; set; }
    public List<Comments> Comments{ get; set; }
    public List<Views> Views{ get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get this information using Linq group join, so that I get child collection.

```
IEnumerable<Product> _products = _context.Product.GroupJoin(_context.Rating, p=>p.id, r=>r.PID, (Product, Rating) => new Product(){
    //fill fields here
});
```

But how to group other tables as well into single database query.

Thanks

Comment: linq-to-sql handles grouping the queries automatically when you commit changes. What are you asking?

Comment: Try code like this : IEnumerable<Product> _products = (from p in _context.Product
     join r in _context.Rating on p.id equals r.id
     Join s in _context.Sales on p.id equals s.id
     select new { p = p, r = r, s = s}).Select(x => new Product() { ..... }

Comment: I want to result into parent child format as mentioned in class. That is the region I did group join. I guess simple join gives all the records into a flat format. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `GroupJoin`, you can just look up the matches directly to construct the `Product` object:

```
IEnumerable<Product> _products = _context.Product.Select(product => new Product() {
    Id = product.id,
    Name = product.name,
    Ratings = _context.Rating.Where(r => r.PID == product.id).ToList(),
    // ... other lists similar
});
```

As pointed out in comments, the above query could generate three sub-queries for every product.

You can use `GroupJoin` if you create anonymous objects to hold the intermediate results:

```
var _products = _context.Product.GroupJoin(_context.Rating, p => p.id, r => r.PID, (p, rs) => new { p, rs })
                                .GroupJoin(_context.Comment, prs => prs.p.id, c => c.PID, (prs, cs) => new { prs.p, prs.rs, cs })
                                .GroupJoin(_context.View, prs => prs.p.id, v => v.PID, (prscs, vs) => new Product() {
                                    Id = prscs.p.id,
                                    Name = prscs.p.name,
                                    Ratings = prscs.rs.ToList(),
                                    Comments = prscs.cs.ToList(),
                                    Views = vs.ToList()
                                });
```

Comment: This could be expensive operation. As for every product, it would fire one Rating, View and Comment query.

Comment: Good point, though I am disappointed LINQ to SQL isn't smart enough to convert to a single query?

Comment: This group join works. But generated SQL in LINQPad is huge. Infact looks like group join and inner query both generate similar SQL. It fire one Rating, View and Comment query per product record.

Comment: The `GroupJoin` didn't generate a SQL `JOIN` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this;

```
        var records = _context.Product
            .GroupJoin(_context.Ratings, p => p.Id, r => r.PID, (p, r) => new { Product = p, Ratings = r})
            .GroupJoin(_context.Comments, p => p.Product.Id, c => c.PID, (p, c) => new { p.Product, p.Ratings, Comments = c})
            .GroupJoin(_context.Views, p => p.Product.Id, v => v.PID, (p, v) => new { p.Product, p.Ratings, p.Comments, Views = v })
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.Product.Id,
                Name = p.Product.Name,
                Comments = p.Comments,
                Ratings = p.Ratings,
                Views = p.Views
            })
            .ToList().Select(x => new Product
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Comments = x.Comments.ToList(),
                Ratings = x.Ratings.ToList(),
                Views = x.Views.ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe an additional SQL statement will be fired for every record the first ToList generates, depending on the return set generating and executing hundreds to thousands of SQL statements.